# Reload Data table with new parameter in ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have added a datatable with an AJAX call in my application. Its working fine, but I need to add some custom filters.

Here is my code

```
<table id="mydatatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td>Email</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<script>
    $("#mydatatable").DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            url: "ajax.php?action=datatable",
            "type": 'POST',
        },
        "order": [[2, "desc"]],
    });
</script>
```

now I have added custom select box for age >15, >25, >35 on that select box change I need to make AJAX call and refresh the datatable

Answer (score 3):

You can supply data from the select box to your `ajax.php` script by using [`ajax.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) option. Then use [`ajax.reload()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) API method to reload the data when value of select box changes.

Change your `ajax.php` to filter data based on supplied `age` request parameter.

For example:

```js
$("#mydatatable").DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "ajax.php?action=datatable",
        "data": function(data){
           data.age = $('#select-age').val();
        },
        "type": 'POST',
    },
    "order": [[2, "desc"]],
});

// Handle event when select box value changes
$('#select-age').on('change', function(){
   // Reload data 
   $("#mydatatable").DataTable().ajax.reload();
});
```

Comment: I want to pass new parameters in `$("#mydatatable").DataTable().ajax.reload();`

Comment: try $("#mydatatable").DataTable().ajax.url('url with updated params').load();